# Create table in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

Can I create a table in Netezza such that the number of columns are created dynamically that is based on the user input?

Backgroud -
I am trying to implement Pearson Coefficient using Netezza system. This is my homework problem.

My Approch - 
I will create an (n x m) random matrix (values of n and m is entered as a parameter). And then create a file in which this matrix will be stored. Then I want to use this file to create a table in Netezza. Then using UDXs I want to calculate correlation between two columns.
My UDX is complete which will accept two column numbers as inputs and give the correlation between them as output.

Comment: If you tried hard enough, probably.  What have you tried so far and what happened when you tried it.  By the way, in real life, what you are attempting might be unwise, so it's a good thing you mentioned this is an academic exercise.

Comment: Are you asking about the overall progress of my homework? As far as my question is concerned I tried searching the net but it looks like we must have to enter the exact schema of the table which in this case is unknown.

Comment: Your question says you want to create a table.  Your comment alludes to the schema of a table that does not yet exist. Perhaps the user input will lead you to the answer.